# Visualize radioactive gamma rays & their absorption in materials using cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, mathematics

there is a very nice [tutorial](http://blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/419-tutorial-absorption-in-cycles.html) showing the mathematics behind light absorption - the amount of light is getting less during it's move through colored material. - following the law of Lambert & Beer.

This mathematically approach could be used to visualize the absorption of normally invisible radioactive gamma rays.

Imagine a scene with a radioactive-ray source inside a box made of a absorption-material (could be made of led-, concrete or iron…)
The absorption coefficients for each material can be found in scientific literature and so the mathematics can be adopted)

Questions:

1. Has anyone experience in such an approach or heard about someone else who tried to visualize radioactive emissions with blender?
   (I know there exists very expensive specialized programs to do such calculations, but they are much to expensive for a simple human being - and they are not that entertaining and not as nice as Blender)
2. And how can the amount of light that is not absorbed by the box-material and travels through the absorbing material to the surface be "measured"? Or how can one measure the density of light on the surface of such a box.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: There are optical physics simulators that are able to handle these calculations — do you need to do them accurately in blender for any particular reason?  Can you articular enough of the physical phenomenology to describe what kind of effect, and its tolerances, that you're seeking in Blender?

Answer (score 1):

There are [volumetric materials](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Materials/Volume) in Blender which can visualize such rays.

Blob with hole and radioactive stone inside (volume absorbtion with volume scatter):

[image]

You would "measure" the intensity with pixel value on the surface i guess

But I have an impression from your question that you would like to simulate the absorption or even measure it, you will **not get any precise scientific result from Blender, only artistic.** Blender does not work with real scientific units (except from dimensions) and its calculations take shortcuts to get better performance, its not precise.

That's why that specialized software is so expensive, it actually simulates it all.

Comment: It could probably be done with scripts controling the absorbtion depending on real material properties and sort of boolean to render slices. But I can't help.